# Use Azure ACS on Windows Form aplication

Tags: windows, winforms, azure, credentials, acs

I'm using Azure ACS to deal with the user authentication in my site, now I'm building a Windows Form App where the user needs to authenticate with the credentials that are used in the web site.
There is anyway to implement Azure ACS with windows forms application?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use Azure Authentication Library (AAL).  Here is an example.  The client application is WPF, but it could just as easily be a Windows Form App.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AAL-Native-App-to-REST-de57f2cc

Answer (score 2):

i am not sure if you can do this directly from the application but i suggest doing so through a WCF or a web services.  you can work with ACS with WCF,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185912.aspx